# BAT file - how to create folders and rename files with non english characters

Tags: batch-file

I have a long list of folders that I need to create, for this I used `MKDIR` but when I run it, folder names that have special words such as chinese characters, vietnamese, danish and so on get created incorrectly, so for example:

```
MKDIR "Ålborg Institut"
```

Results in a folder named:

```
┼lborg Institut
```

Comment: Encoding issues are mostly a pain in the a** but it get's even worse when you have to deal with them in batch files. My advice: switch to PowerShell. It's also a windows built-in tool and has way better options dealing with encoding issues. It's also possible that "rewriting" your code in PowerShell will already solve the problem as it is better in recognising special chars from different languages.

Comment: Try to change the [code page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) by the [`chcp` command](http://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html); perhaps `chcp 1252` could help. By the way: where is the *question*, a sentence ended with a `?` symbol? ;-)

Comment: thank you both (@MichaelS  / @aschipfl)  for your replies, I am sorry for the vague "question", I had been trying to get this to work for hours and was exhausted and my writting skills were suffering ;(  I'll try the chcp command as you suggest and will get back to you with results, as for powershell I am not familiar with that programming language and my deadline wont allow me to learn it.

Comment: WORKED! I entered chcp 65001 since the export was in UTF-8 format and the folders were created successfully. All characters worked.  many thanks!